# Testing a variable assignment in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Does anyone know why this test is failing? All I'm trying to do is prove this method (starting positions) assigns the current_room to the starting_room and I can't get a value returned for current_room?

```
class Room
  attr_reader :starting_room, :current_room  

  def initialize
    @starting_room = "Room 5"
    @current_room = nil
  end

  def starting_positions
    @current_room = starting_room
  end

end


 before(:each) do
   @room = Room.new
 end

 describe '#starting_positions' do
  it 'sets the starting location to the current location' do
    @room.instance_variable_set(:@starting_room, "Room 5")
    expect(@room.current_room).to eql("Room 5")
  end
end
```

My output:

```
 Failures:

 1) Room#starting_positions sets the starting location to the current location
 Failure/Error: expect(@room.current_room).to eql("Room 5")

   expected: "Room 5"
        got: nil
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems `@room` is nil. please add `p @room.class`. Then I don't see the readers in the class, where are they?

Comment: Ahhh sorry, there are readers, I just didn't copy them over (doing that now...)

Comment: so then `@room` where is the assignment to it?

Comment: hmmm, I'm not too sure what you mean. Are you referring to the new @room object that is created with before(:each)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `@starting_room` and don't assign `current_room`. You need trigger `starting_positions`

```
before(:each) do
  @room = Room.new
end

describe '#starting_positions' do
  it 'sets the starting location to the current location' do
    @room.instance_variable_set(:@starting_room, "Room 5")
    @room.starting_positions
    expect(@room.current_room).to eql("Room 5")
  end
end
```